# Data not fills correctly in DataTable using OleDbDataAdapter

Tags: c#, excel, import, datatable, oledbdataadapter

When I try to import excel sheet, it does not fetches some integer values. I am using *DevExpress GridControl for exporting data from Grid*. After export I ***change value of some cell's(which have blank value) to integer*** let's say 123 then on import it does not fetches that integer value in DataTable.

I have posted same issue on DevExpress support center "[Export values in Improper Cell](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T248006)". They said the issue is from MSDN not by their control's. Please download the sample from given DevExpress link & also watch the video attached for more detailed information.

I have used following code for import.

```
 private System.Data.DataTable GetDataTableFromFile(string fileName)
    {
        string query = string.Empty;
        //// string connectionString = "provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source='" + fileName + "';Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;";
        string connectionStringV12 = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;";
        string connectionStringV4 = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data source={0};Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;";
        System.Data.DataTable dataTable = new System.Data.DataTable();
        OleDbConnection obedbConnection = new OleDbConnection(string.Format(connectionStringV4, fileName));
        try
        {
            if (obedbConnection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                obedbConnection.Open();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            ////Diff. Connetion String
            obedbConnection = new OleDbConnection(string.Format(connectionStringV12, fileName));
        }

        ////Get First SheetName From Xls File 
        string sheetName = GetSheetNameFromFile(obedbConnection);

        if (sheetName != null)
        {
            ////Query for Reading all Data from File
            query = "select * from [" + sheetName + "]";
        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(query))
        {
            OleDbDataAdapter data = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, obedbConnection);
            data.Fill(dataTable);
        }
        return dataTable;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets First SheetName of excel File 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="con">Connection object.</param>
    /// <returns>return sheet name.</returns>
    private string GetSheetNameFromFile(OleDbConnection con)
    {
        try
        {
            if (con.State != ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                con.Open();
            }
            var oledbTableSchema = con.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, new object[] { null, null, null, "Table" });
            if (oledbTableSchema.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                string sheetName = oledbTableSchema.Rows[0].ItemArray[2].ToString();
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(sheetName))
                {
                    throw new Exception("Sheet Not Found");

                }
                return sheetName;
            }
            return string.Empty;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

So, Can any one please help me to solve this issue?

Comment: Do you have problem in Importing or exporting the files

Comment: I adviced you to import the excel files using ExcelReader dll. https://exceldatareader.codeplex.com/

Comment: Yes that's the other workaround... But first I want to ask you why this happens??

Comment: That  might be because xls you are trying to open contains columns in non relevant format. eg the column that containts number might be formatted with datetime format or genral  format

Comment: I am using `ExcelReader` in two big projects with no complaints

Comment: Yes but then How it work's with string if I put text in that Cell, it works. If CellFormat is Text,then integer values not get fetched in DataTable..

Comment: Ok I will try to use `ExcelReader` but I also want the cause which help me to know why not to use`OleDbDataAdapter`?

Comment: Do you have all the values in that columns is text or integer or datetime

Comment: values are exported in general format & another null values export's in Text format... but actually after analyzing a lott CellFormat is not an issuee...

Comment: please visit that given DevExpress link for more detailed information...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the **IMEX = 1** property to my connection string, solved my issue.

```
    string connectionStringV4 = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data source={0};Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;IMEX=1;";
```

There is also similar behavior reported in the below thread

[Not able to read integer in excel file consistantly](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/0ba68d1f-609a-435f-9dbb-e1d365b4e42f/not-able-to-read-integer-in-excel-file-consistantly)

For more detailed answer please go to following link :

[Data not fills correctly in DataTable using OleDbDataAdapter](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/000858e5-5f68-4f9a-84c0-02154a82679b/data-not-fills-correctly-in-datatable-using-oledbdataadapter?forum=csharpgeneral)